# linux bash sed-command with variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have a variable in a linux bash ".sh" script

```
$data="test_1"
```

now I want to create a new variable ($name) that contains only the part of $data before the underscore, so

```
$name="test"
```

I thought of doing this with sed

```
name=$(echo "$dataset" | sed 's/_.*//');
```

but this doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$data="test_1"` is wrong. Variables are set without the dollar sign: `data="test_1"`.

Comment: To me it does work, even though it is best to say `echo "${data%%_*}"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to call an external process(`sed`). Instead you can use shell's parameter substitution like this:

```
$ data="test_1"

$ echo "${data%%_*}"
test
```

`${var%%Pattern}` Remove from `$var` the longest part of Pattern that matches the back end(from the right) of `$var`.

`${var%Pattern}` for removing shortest pattern

More info on parameter substitution can be found [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html).

You can store it in a variable like this:

```
$ name="${data%%_*}"

$ echo "$name"
test
```

Comment: but this doesn't store it in a new variable?